# What technologies exist to find an aircraft position after it crashed out of line of sight?

Tags: avionics, gnss

What is the best way in the manner of products to find an aircraft after it crashed out of line of sight. Are there defined standards, and what are the selection criteria?

Comment: How big of a UAV? If they are large enough, an FAA registration number is required to be visible on the outside.

Comment: [Since you should not be flying it out of line of sight](https://jrupprechtlaw.com/section-107-31-visual-line-sight-aircraft-operation) it should not be crashing anywhere you cant watch it crash...

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about tge type of aircraft and type of mission you are flying? It seems to me that first of all, you don't want your 200 pounds drone to crash as it is a safety hazard to those on the ground. I would recommend constant telemetry between the drone and a operating station so that the location can be tracked. How you achieve that depends on the drone, its mission and the environment.

Comment: The drone could well be within the operator's line of sight, right up until the point that the craft falls to earth.  The requirement is line-of-sight to the drone, not to the ground under it.  That all said, opinions & product recommendations are entirely off-topic here. VTC

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the UAV.  Many consumer UAVs eg DJI, etc. track the position of the drone via GPS and log it so you can find the crash site quickly.  Others emit beeping noises so you can locate it by sound.

Comment: Thanks. What about crash position inducator cpi systems, i havent seen any uav mounted with these system just for helicopter. And following voice signal may be difficult to hear. What is your opinion about cpi?

Answer (score 0):

Any recent Android mobile phone has "[find my device](https://icdn8.digitaltrends.com/image/find-my-device-desktop-2-1500x1000.jpg)" feature now, even if no additional apps are installed.

Attach an Android phone with the dedicated Google account logged into to the AC and you will be able to find the location, say, by visiting Google website from your tablet. You can buy a ruggedized phone that is more likely to survive the crash.

Comment: Good idead, how to handle battery problem guess will operate 10k hours and where will i mount it to guarante it will survive after crashed and signals not blocked?

Comment: @K.Ense "operate 10k hours" Find me a battery source that is light enough to put in a phone and fly it around on a consumer drone and will operate _anything_ (beyond a simple digital wrist watch, _not_ a smart watch) for 10k hours & I'll pay you good money for it!

Comment: @FreeMan here i want to say that i dont want to charge it before every flight so only way is continusly connect battery to supply and we can use 10k hours?

Comment: @K.Ense 10,000 hours is 416.6 _days_. Do you know of _any_ rechargeable battery powered device that will last that long in continuous use? _Especially_ something as power hungry as a smart phone? Also "guarantee it will survive after a crash" - I've seen people drop cell phones 1 meter from their pocket and break the screen. I think that guarantee is highly unlikely in a flyable package.